# Extract unique minimum distance pairs using each element only once

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

From a distance matrix I have generated a dataframe consisting of three columns.

Column x and y contains all the unique combinations of the ids: a, b, c, and d. (The id's are simplified for illustration purposes, the actual data consists of strings of digits, i.e. '1234', '2323', '2443')

The test matrix is sorted by distance as I'm interested in all the unique combinations containing the lowest distance measures.

Is there a function capable of extracting unique pairs from columns x and y such that each element only appear once in either column x and y?

In the following scenario I am interested in only one pair containing A, one pair containing B, and so on.

Example:

Input:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 'b', 0.1], ['b', 'a', 0.1], 
                              ['c', 'a', 0.2], ['a', 'c', 0.2], 
                              ['b', 'd', 0.3], ['d', 'b', 0.3], 
                              ['c', 'd', 0.4], ['d', 'c', 0.4]]), columns=['x', 'y', 'distance'])  
test
   x  y distance
0  a  b      0.1
1  b  a      0.1
2  c  a      0.2
3  a  c      0.2
4  b  d      0.3
5  d  b      0.3
6  c  d      0.4
7  d  c      0.4
```

Desired output:

```
   x  y distance
0  a  b      0.1
1  c  d      0.4
```

Whether the output presents (a, b) or (b,a) is not important.

Note that dropping duplicates in this example is not sufficient, as pair (c, d) and (d, c) would be removed.

EDIT:

Here's a (messy) while loop that provide the right output, but I was hoping for a less complex solution to speed up the for loop in which this function will be nested.

```
i = 0

while i < len(test):

    comp_x = test.loc[i,'x']
    comp_y = test.loc[i,'y']

    test.loc[i+1:len(test),['x','y']] = test.loc[i+1:len(test),['x','y']][~test.loc[i+1:len(test),:][['x','y']].isin([comp_x])]
    test.loc[i+1:len(test),['x','y']] = test.loc[i+1:len(test),['x','y']][~test.loc[i+1:len(test),:][['x','y']].isin([comp_y])]

    test.dropna(inplace=True)
    test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    i+=1

print(test)
   x  y distance
0  a  b      0.1
1  c  d      0.4
```

Comment: what about b + d?

Comment: @Datanovice My understanding is that because b already appears in the (a, b) pair, the (b, d) pair is not included in the expected output.

Comment: Correct, since b is already included in (a,b) it should not appear again in (b,d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test to see if this is what you are after:

```
xy=set()
records=[]

for e in test.itertuples():
    if ((e[1] not in xy) and (e[2] not in xy)):
        records.append(e)
        xy.update(list(e[1:3]))

pd.DataFrame(records).set_index('Index').rename_axis('')

    x   y   distance        
0   a   b   0.1
6   c   d   0.4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Allen, it seems to work. As can be seen in the edit, I also have a while loop that does the job. Do you have any ideas as to how I might avoid having to use a for or while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by combining the columns 'x' & 'y' and drop duplicates from this new column

```py
test['filter'] = test[['x', 'y']].apply(lambda row: '-'.join(sorted(row, key=lambda y: ord(y))), axis=1)

test = test.drop_duplicates(subset=['filter']).reset_index()[['x', 'y', 'distance']]

# solution
#    x  y distance
# 0  a  b      0.1
# 1  c  a      0.2
# 2  b  d      0.3
# 3  c  d      0.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond! 

The method is however not providing the desired output posted above.

It is a very simplified example of the actual data, and therefore safe to drop duplicates in the distance column if you want to get rid of one of the (a,b), (b,a) rows.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

the idea is to create a new series and sort your values along their axis and use a sort_by

```
s = test[["x", "y"]].sum(axis=1).apply(
    lambda x: sorted(x)
).explode().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)


s1 = (
    s.groupby(s.index // 2)
    .agg(",".join)
    .str.split(",", expand=True)
    .rename(columns={0: "x", 1: "y"})
)

test.sort_values("distance").loc[(test["x"].isin(s1["x"])) & (test["y"].isin(s1["y"]))]

out:

   x  y distance
0  a  b      0.1
6  c  d      0.4
```

Comment: b is used twice in the resulting output.
It can only be used once.

Comment: updated @SJeppesen but it's a solution based on your input - you'll need to change if your data is dif.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Not sure what your mean though. Your first solution was not a solution based on my input since (b,d) should not be included as given by the output presented. Your second solution works, but explode() only works for one-digit ID's. For illustration purposes I've used a,b,c,d instead of i.e. company ticker codes ('GOOGL', 'APPL', 'FB', etc.) or strings of digits ('12345', '2342', '33333'). But your right, it is a solution given the simplified input presented. But only a solution if you have a very limited number of unique id's.